# symbol or notation for an occurrence happening 3 times in a row

Tags: notation

I am looking for a symbol or notation to indicate that an event has happened 3 times in a row.

Basically, I am plotting daily temperatures and I have indicated days on the plot, with a point symbol, where the mean temperature has been below 60 F for a at least 3 consecutive days. I need to indicate on the plot legend what those point symbols indicate. I cannot seem to find the right notation.

Is there a mathematical symbol or notation for an event occurring for at least n consecutive days?

Comment: You can use colors to differentiate the number of occurrences.  For example, one occurrence would be a red dot, two would be orange, etc.

Comment: Yes. I am doing that with the legend symbology. I am looking for the best way to label such symbology in the plot legend.So if I use a red dot for days that are part of a series of 3 consecutive days below 60, the text I am using with that red dot is currently "Mean Temp <60 F x 3". I am looking for a mathematical notation or symbol to replace the "x 3" portion.